# calling c++ dll functions/API in C# project

Tags: c#, c++

I am a newbie to C#, and finding difficult to call a C++ API from C# project
I have created file "socket.dll" which has C++ API's. Below is the snippet

source.cpp+source.h->socket.dll

```
 #include "Source.h"

 void PiblRequestCallback(PibMsgConf &msg, void *param)
 {
  cout << "In PibRequestCallback" << endl;
 }

 uint32_t GetPib() 
 {

  return 25;
 }
```

I am calling the above API "GetPib" from C# project. Below is the code snippet:

(WindowsFormsAPP)

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 namespace WindowsFormsApp1
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         [DllImport("socket.dll")]
         public static extern UInt32 GetPib();

         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void GetPib_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             pib_len_tbox.Text = GetPib().ToString();
         }
     }
 }
```

While running the C# code snippet I get error

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 
'GetPib' in DLL 'socket.dll'.'
```

What changes to be made in socket.dll file or C# project to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import external function:

```
     [DllImport("socket.dll", EntryPoint = "getpib")]
     public static extern UInt32 GetPib();
```

if entrypoint not found use dumpbin to find entry point (use visual studio command prompt)

```
dumpbin /exports [dll path]
```

Comment: i ran the below command:

Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file socket.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg

        1000 .data

        2000 .idata

        4000 .rdata

        1000 .reloc

        1000 .rsrc


       11000 .text

       10000 .textbss

I didn't get any "getpib signature"

Comment: add  __declspec(dllexport) to function getpib signature

Comment: now i am able to see getpib signature after running dumpbin, but in the project, i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your dll actually contains the signature of the function.

Usually `__declspec(dllexport)` is used for methods that get exported for msvc compilers.

Comment: now i am able to see getpib signature after adding _declspec(dllexport) to dll using the dumpbin binary, but in the project, i am still getting the same error.